# ¿Como llamar una función C# desde jqGrid?

Tags: c#, jqgrid

Necesito desde el método OnselectRow de jqGrid llamar un método de C# enviando dos parámetros a el método en C#.

Necesito esto ya que al cargar una jqGrid deseo que al seleccionar una de las filas me cargue uno de los valores (esto ya se como) y quiero poder cargar otra grid evaluando estos valores (a través de un método en C#). Quisiera saber si alguien sabe como es posible llevar a cabo este llamado.

Cabe aclarar que trabajo en asp.net

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para invocar codigo servidor desde el cliente vas a tener que usar `$.ajax` de jquery, basicamente invocarias un `WebMethod` definido en el aspx

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

[Web Service in ASP.NET (Return JSON and XML): Part 4](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4/)

como veras defines en el servidor un webmethod que devolver un objeto serializado a json que podras usar en el cliente mediente javascript

Comment: muchas gracias, al final logre sacarlo haciendo uso de esta información